# (simple) SQL query for date conversion in presto SQL

Tags: sql, presto

I'm struggling a bit with prestoDB SQL date logic on a super simple query and was wondering if someone could offer a solution?

I have some dates in this format stored as a varchar

```
20180901
20180902
20180903
20180904
20180905
20180906

etc
```

I store these in 'lastseen'

I'd like a query where I can say

```
select * from abc where lastseen = (lastseen - 1 day)
```

so the result would be for example:

```
20180902 = 20180901
```

or

```
20180901 = 20180831
```

and so on.

Can't seem to work it out, so welcome any solutions or pointers.

Comment: You can use `date_parse()` to convert a string to a date *(found with an internet search engine)*.  Provided you are sufficiently happy that the format of those strings is ***guaranteed***.  As for the rule you want, well, umm, `20180902` ***never equals*** `20180901`, so I'm not sure what you want...  I recommend showing the example output you want from the example input you've shown.

Comment: Thanks Mat.  The example I meant was that for a given date string of 20180902 with 1 day taken away from it, the result would be the string 20180901.

So in this case, lets say I wanted run run the query today (20180904), I'd get:

select * from abc where lastseen = (lastseen - 1 day)
would result in all records where lastseen is 20180903 returned from abc.

Comment: So, the pseudo-sql you want is `SELECT lastseen, date_parse(lastseen) - interval 1 day FROM abc`?   https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/datetime.html

Comment: The SQL would be:

select * from abc where "p"."lastseen" = date_parse("p"."lastseen") - interval 1 day

Comment: But that's NEVER true. It's like staying `WHERE 2-1=2`

Answer (score 0):

I believe something like this would work.

```
cast(lastseen AS date) = cast(lastseen as date) - interval '1' day
```

Of course, this will only work if you have good data through the entire table. It will also cause a `Query` to always return nothing if you put it into the `WHERE` clause.

Could you be more specific on what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: But how can a date ever equal itself minus 1?

Comment: It cannot. Unless something funky is going on with the data. That's why I stated that putting this in a `WHERE` clause would return nothing and asked the original poster to clarify their intentions.